# How to update one table in MYSQL from another table? with extra values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have two tables that are similar.

```
Table word
column names: id, name, describe
1 bob Is a cat
2 Sam Not a giraffe
3 Gub Like a cat

Table temp
column names: id, name, describe
1 bob Is a cat
2 Sam Not a giraffe
3 Gub Like a cat
4 Col The other one
```

I am currently using this to update table word from table temp, but the 4th value isn't being added. How would I do that?

```
UPDATE temp p, word pp
SET pp.name= p.name, pp.describe = p.describe
WHERE pp.id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :: INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO word(id, name, describe) SELECT id, name, describe FROM temp 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET word.name = temp.name, word.describe = temp.describe;
```

Comment: I am getting an error
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET word.name = t

Comment: Also, id is auto incrementing, should it also be UNIQUE?

Comment: It doesn't work with SET, but after i removed it, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to copy values from one table to another, keeping the same `id`. In this case, you can't put condition WHERE pp.id = p.id. This way, it would only copy rows with `id` that already exist in 'word' table, skipping any unique rows. You can use "INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to get arround it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

the last one would need an insert statement because it does not exist yet

INSERT INTO word pp SELECT * FROM temp left join word on on temp.id = word.id where temp.id IS NULL